# Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message Django Outlook/hotmail

Tags: python, django, hotmail

If someone had this issue, I will be sincerely thankful for your help.

I'm having this error sending local email with hotmail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/consumer.py", line 169, in process_task
    task_value = self.huey.execute(task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/api.py", line 357, in execute
    result = task.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/api.py", line 842, in execute
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/contrib/djhuey/__init__.py", line 108, in inner
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/code/app/tasks.py", line 89, in send_email
    email_message.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 111, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 127, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 888, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (432, b'4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded [Hostname=DM5PR19MB1050.namprd19.prod.outlook.com]')
ERROR   process_task    Unhandled exception in worker thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/consumer.py", line 169, in process_task
    task_value = self.huey.execute(task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/api.py", line 357, in execute
    result = task.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/api.py", line 842, in execute
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/huey/contrib/djhuey/__init__.py", line 108, in inner
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/code/app/tasks.py", line 89, in send_email
    email_message.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 111, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 127, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 888, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:050B0000, 17.43559:0000000094000000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140F248214004010F1030000, 20.50032:140F248285174010F1030000, 0.35180:0A00B681, 255.23226:F1030000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:0A00F784, 16.55847:EC000000, 17.43559:0000000068010000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140F2482140000100A00F736, 20.50032:140F24828517001181170000, 0.35180:00000000, 255.23226:00000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:140F2482, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:A4010000, 0.37692:05000780, 0.37948:00000600, 5.33852:00000000534D545000000000, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B32303A44, 7.57132:00000000000000003A346638, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 8.45434:0000060075AF4541000000000000000032000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E303534382E3032303A444D35505231394D42313035303A34663832663161652D373465382D343830632D623637302D34326236313339313335383200401005000780, 255.1750:0A00FC83, 255.31418:41010000, 0.22753:0A001E85, 255.21817:DC040000, 4.60547:DC040000, 0.21966:4B010000, 4.30158:DC040000 [Hostname=DM5PR19MB1050.namprd19.prod.outlook.com]')
```

That is my configuration on settings.py
I try changing the port to 587, try with gmail account but doesn't work

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably missing "Email From" variable either in settings.py or your view.
Try this:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.live.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@hotmail.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'youremail@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_FROM = 'youremail@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` is used in stock Django views, but if you have your own custom one, then you can import those variables as well:

```
from django.conf import settings

send_mail(
    mail_subject,
    message,
    settings.EMAIL_FROM,
    [to_email],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Comment: The above error also occurs, if you pass an improper user.

Answer (score -1):

1. This can be solved very easily by adding the following line in **settings.py**:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "support@urmail.com"

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "support@urmail.com"
```

Make sure that both `EMAIL_HOST_USER`  and `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` is same email Id.

2. `send_mail` also will work perfectly but there is no facility to add attachment in that option.